# Spring Rest with many view representation for same REST resource

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm looking for a way to keep more than one view representation (for smartphone, web, other) of data for the same REST resource or how to make a same resource if it subdivides into several hierarchically according to the volume of data.

I even thought without doing something with the HTTP Header accept, as according to the header, it would send more or less data.

I read about the BFF (Martin Fowler), I found it interesting, but I do not know how to do this in practice or even already implement in a Spring Boot

Does anyone have any suggestions of what to do or what to start looking for?